# Text.contains on multiple columns with multiple words - Power Query

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, powerquery

I'm working on a data cleaning and I'm trying to create a custom column checking if there are a list of words in multiple columns (in the whole table).

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "TEST", each if Text.Contains([Action] or [Results] or [Outcome Name] = [Key]) then true else null)
```

but it gives me error.
I'm not interested to find out in which column the words are located, but only in which rows there are located

[Key] is another table with the list of words that is linked to the main table.

Someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I would like to avoid to create multiple columns (one for each column)

Answer (score 1):

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "TEST", each if Text.Contains([Action], [Key]) then true else if Text.Contains([Results],[Key]) then true else if Text.Contains([Outcome Name], [Key]) then true else null)
```

Never mind, I found the solution, Thank you for reading the question

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more elegant way

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "TEST", each List.Contains({[Action],[Results],[Outcome Name]}, [Key]), type logical)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-contains

Hope you like it